# Complex plane iteration of z^z

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation, complex-dynamics

How can I identify when the iterative sequence $z \to z^z$ is not going to head for infinity for some starting value $z$?

For example, $z=1$ is fixed, since $1^1 = 1$. If $z$ is real and between 0 and 1, the iteration heads for 1, where it stays. When starting $z$ is real and greater than 1, then the iteration heads for infinity.

When $z$ starts out negative, however, complex numbers quickly come into play. $-1+0i$, for instance, quickly zeros in on $1+0i$; however, $-0.5+0i$ quickly exceeds computing parameters. Restating $z$ as $x + yi$ and showing the iterations to the point of exceeding computing capacity are as follows:

$$-0.5 \to -1.414213562i \to 691.6428072-369.0287525i \to NAN.$$

Guidelines for complex exponentiation here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

This reminds me of the iteration behind the Mandelbrot set: $z\to z^2+c$. In the case of the Mandelbrot set, however, it's easy to identify when a $z$ is reached that will head for infinity (when the absolute value of $z$ exceeds 2). When plotting the Mandelbrot set on the complex plane, the program merely needs to catch when 2 is exceeded, and excludes the point being evaluated from the set.

I would really like to see a plot of the set of points $x+iy$ on the complex plane where the iteration $x+yi \to (x+yi)^{x+yi}$ does not head for infinity. I suspect all such points zero-in on the value $1+0i$ but I am not sure they do. There may be other 'equilibrium' values, or there may be values where a repeated cycle forms (as is the case for points in the Mandelbrot set).

I have done a plot for this, however, in this case I was simply assuming that the iteration was headed for infinity whenever $x$ or $y$ exceeded 10 - I'm not sure this is the case! Another problem is that the plot sometimes exclude points when they come close to $0+0i$ (calculation problem - I could fix this but the other problem of excessively high values remains).

Here's the plot image:

[image]

Obviously, the set is fractal in nature, so I would really like to see it calculated correctly.

Most of the points excluded in the plot are excluded because they yield an iteration where $x$ or $y$ exceeds 10. I am pretty sure, however, that there are some very high numbers that do not head for infinity - having the imaginary unit in the exponent means that a very high positive input can become a very high negative input in the next iteration, such that the high negative real number in the exponent creates a real number in the iteration following that one that is very close to zero, thus zeroing-in on $1 + 0i$ in iterations following that.

I even suspect that numbers that exceed my computers computing capacity (something like $10^{360}$ or something) may eventually come back to $1+0i$ if my computer could just compute further iterations. Might this in fact be the case for all starting values that contain a non-zero imaginary component? Could this be proven one way or the other?

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might be useful ...

Comment: I edited your post so that it follows standard mathematical conventions more closely and uses MathJax for typesetting. I'm not able to verify some of your computations, however. In particular, I compute $(-\sqrt{2}i)^{-\sqrt{2}i}$ to be approximately $0.09568 - 0.05105298i$, rather than $691.6428072-369.0287525i$, as you've got. My picture also looks a bit different.

Comment: +1 for a great picture.  If you want to iterate $z^z$, you should really think carefully about the multi-valued properties of that function.  I think the  the smooth-looking edges in your picture probably can be explained as where your computer jumps from one branch of $z^z$ to another.

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't think it really makes sense consider whether the orbit escapes to $\infty$ or not because $z^z$ is very small when $z$ is a negative number with large absolute value. Note that $z^z$ shares this property with $e^z$ and I'd expect the global structure of the iterates of these to functions to have a lot in common.

On a local level, we might expect the iteration of $f(z)=z^z$ to have a lot in common with its quadratic approximation near its fixed point, since:
$$f(z) = 1+(z-1)+(z-1)^2+O\left((z-1)^3\right).$$
Thus, we might examine 
$$g(z) = 1+(z-1)+(z-1)^2.$$
Indeed, both these functions have fixed points at $z_0=1$ with multiplier (value of the derivative) equal to one. In the case of $g(z)$, it's well known that the the disk of radius $1/2$ centered at the point $1/2$ shrinks to $1$ under iteration of $g$. See, for example, Example 6.5.3 of Alan Beardon's *Iteration of Rational Functions*, which examines a very similar function. This is also illustrated in the figures below:

[image]

Thus, we might examine the behavior of the iteration of $f$ on this same disk. The result is:

[image]

Now, the point of all this is the following:

> Once an iterate of $f$ enters the disk of radius $1/2$ centered at the
>   point $1/2$, we can be sure that further iterates will converge slowly
>   to $1$.

Thus, we have a strategy for generating a picture: Iterate until we either enter that disk, overflow, or reach a maximum bailout. The result looks like so:

[image]

Note that this does have a bit in common with images of some exponential Julia sets, like [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Exponential_maps#/media/File:Exp-esc.png), as we might expect. The image also seems to suggest an answer to your question concerning the orbits of points off of the positive real axis - namely, the picture indicates that *most* such points to eventually converge to 1 but not *all* points. We can in fact prove this by finding points off of the positive real axis that map to some real number larger than 1. For example, 
$$z=2.469470714651633682 + 3.01399440678144i$$
maps (approximately) to 2, as you can verify numerically.